# How to JUnit test multiple .java files in Eclipse

Tags: junit

Do you know of a way for students to give me their .java file via Google Drive and then have those files be unit tested?

Right now I have students upload their file to a GDrive folder. Those folders end up being source folders in my Eclipse. I like this because then all the .java files can have the same names - which is nice for testing. But then I have multiple files with the same name and Eclipse throws out errors because of it. Is there a way around this?

Could students upload their files to a single common folder with different names (e.g. Program_DS, Program_TK) and then I could make a unit test that creates, somehow, a dynamic name for an object? For instance, `Program_** p = new Program_** ();`.

I'm just not sure of a nice way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a nice setup :)

Comment: Why don't you set up a continuous integration server and a repo so when your students commit & push it auto processes the unit tests?

Comment: To be clear, have you asked your students to implement class `X` and you've already written a unit test for `X` and you need to validate that their implementation passes the test?

Comment: @Duncan That is correct.

Comment: @JNYRanger I didn't know this was possible. I'll have to look into this. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: http://jenkins-ci.org/   Is a good free one to help you get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define an interface that your students must implement. They should name their implementations in non-conflicting ways, e.g.

```java
public interface Class1TestA {
 // ...
}

public class FirstnameLastnameClass1TestA implements Class1TestA {
  // ...
}
```

Then I would change your test to be a parameterized JUnit test. In your parameter-generating method, you should scan the classpath for classes implementing `Class1TestA`. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader, as you educational folks like to say.

Your parameterized test should take one value in the constructor: a `ClassTestA` instance. Each of your tests will then be executed against this instance.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this so I'll look into it. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Probably everything but more specifically the "parameterized" JUnit test. I've made a JUnit test and a suite but I'm not sure how to do parameterized. Then I'll have to figure out how to do a parameter-generating method and how to scan a classpath.